# PHP File downloads when working with images

Tags: php, file, header, echo

I have the following script I think is making a file download instead of displaying text. This script is requested from another file as a function. After it does this anything echoed is downloaded.

If there is no echo an empty PHP file is downloaded.

Could someone please help.

Script:

```
<?php

function stickerCreate($serial,$location){
    ob_start();
    $header_image = "Content-type: image/png";
    header($header_image);
    $imgPath = 'sticker.png';
    $string = $serial;
    $directory = "serial_write/".$string.".png";
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($imgPath);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
    $font = 'arial.ttf';
    $fontSize = 18;
    $x = 300;
    $y = 480;
    imagettftext($image, $fontSize, 0, $x, $y, $color, $font, $location);

    imagepng($image, $directory);
    header_remove("Content-type");
    ob_flush();
}

?>
```

I dont know if it is the header that is doing it or what.

Thanks

Robert

Comment: If you want to show the image, then don't remove the content type header.

Comment: Hey @RalphJohnGalindo you are a legend. Thanks so much. That was brilliant advice and it worked. If you answer the question and place the script without the header_remove I will choose you as the right answer and give you credit.

Comment: Okay. I'll create one. So others can find the answer.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't remove the header, so that browser will display the image normally.

```
<?php

function stickerCreate($serial,$location){
    ob_start();
    $header_image = "Content-type: image/png";
    header($header_image);
    $imgPath = 'sticker.png';
    $string = $serial;
    $directory = "serial_write/".$string.".png";
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($imgPath);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
    $font = 'arial.ttf';
    $fontSize = 18;
    $x = 300;
    $y = 480;
    imagettftext($image, $fontSize, 0, $x, $y, $color, $font, $location);

    imagepng($image, $directory);
    // header_remove("Content-type");
    ob_flush();
}

?>
```